# C# Tcp Webserver Error

Tags: c#, tcp

I experiment at the moment with Webserver in C#.

I have now a simple Timer in my Code which is sending every 10 seconds something to the Connected Client Browser

```
        writer.Write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write("Content-Length: " + content.Length);
        writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Flush();
```

But now i get after the first tick an errormessage:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

In German

> In die Übertragungsverbindung kann keine Daten geschrieben werden: Eine bestehende verbindung Wurde softwaregesteuert
>   Durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen

What is it and how can i fix it ?

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: do you have the exception or the error text thrown? screenshot?

Comment: Where is this error coming from?  The browser that receives the data, or the code above (if it's an exception, which line, and what are the details).  Also, what type is "writer", how was it created and how is it used to write to "Connected Client Browser"?

Comment: @Amitd I added a Screenshot

Comment: @PeterRitchie Thats the complete Error its coming from a simple TCP Connection writer is a Streamwriter

Comment: HTTP does not use NewLine. It uses \n. HTTP is not a text based protocol. It's specified as a binary one.

Comment: The server can/should only write after a request. Drop your timer.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a Content-Length header, your client expects precisely that amount of data. After it reads that data it might as well close the connection, which I suppose is what's  actually  happening.
In http, communication is like this: client requests -> server responds. That's it. You can't push data from the server like you are trying to.

Instead, try making your clients issue a request every 10 seconds and that will work just fine.

Comment: Okey :) so what you mean with your last Sentence ? Maybe a Example? .. Cause my Client is a Browser? And no Program ? And i dont want to write my own Browser for this lol.

Comment: I can't  give you an example because I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I try todo sending Datas to Browser/ Client and changing Text or something in realtime.. like showing a live Clock using my own Webserver cause i dont want trigger every 10 Secounds over Javascript with Ajax or something.

Comment: The correct way to do this is by Ajax calls sent to the server at regular intervals and then modify your DOM within the page JavaScript.

Comment: Also, more like what you are trying to accomplish is something called SignalR which works in ASP.NET, but since you still need to get your head around the basics of http, I wouldn't advise you to follow this route yet.

Comment: Okey Thanks for everything i will read it the next Days :)! 
I know how to work with Ajax and ASP.NET and all. I only was to try a alternative .. like the HipHop Engine from Facebook. 
SignalR sounds nice i will take a look at it.
How you mean that with AJAX ? .. Sending every 10 Secounds a Ping to the Server ? so evvery 10 Secs a AJAX Request ? is it usefull with high traffic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91322/discussion-between-hanselman-and-mihai-caracostea).